# How to do .querySelector() for the current document on a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build some plugin, and I only using JS because it's the mother god of the web.
I'm trying to get elements of the current PAGE! NOT extension TAB of a specific class.

When the window is loads, if any elements with the class provided appear, then return the source of them.

**background.js**

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
    alert(document.querySelector('.xd'));
    function modifyDOM() {
        //You can play with your DOM here or check URL against your regex
        return document.querySelector('.xd');
    }

    //We have permission to access the activeTab, so we can call chrome.tabs.executeScript:
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: modifyDOM //argument here is a string but function.toString() returns function's code
    }, (results) => {
        //Here we have just the innerHTML and not DOM structure

    });

};
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    body {
   min-width:500px;
   height:250px;
   font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding:10px;
   }
   </style>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"> Get Current URL</button>
    <p>You are browsing URL -  <span id="url"></span></p>
    <p>Your Video SRC: <span id="vid-src"></span></p>

    <ul id="links"></ul>

    <button id="test">TEST</button>

    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "New",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage","contextMenus"],

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: 1) The background script runs in a separate hidden background page so you should write a different popup.js and use it in popup.html, not background.js. 2) To access a web page tab you need another separate entity: a content script, [more info](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567) (you seem to know that already but just in case).

Comment: Also, it should be `code: \`(${modifyDOM})()\`` to actually run the injected function.